# SQL Table with a list of repeating values (duplicates) to find

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, aggregate, checksum

I am trying to identify a list of duplicates from a table and my table looks like this:

Column1-Column2

1. 1-1
2. 1-2
3. 1-3
4. 2-1
5. 2-2
6. 2-3
7. 3-1
8. 3-2
9. 3-4
10. 4-1
11. 4-2
12. 4-3
13. 4-4
14. 5-1
15. 5-2
16. 5-4

    - 1 has a group of {1,2,3}
    - 2 has a group of {1,2,3}
    - And are duplicates
    - 3 has a group of {1,2,4}
    - 5 has a group of {1,2,4}
    - And are duplicates
    - 4 has a group of {1,2,3,4}
    - And has no friends ;)

Column 2 really is a varchar column, but I made everything numbers for simplicity sack.

I have been playing with CheckSum_Agg, but it has false positives.  :(

My output would look something like this:

- 1,2
- 3,5

Where I select the min ID for the first column and all of the other values for the second column.  Non-duplicates are omitted.

Another example might look like:

- 1,2
- 1,6
- 3,5
- 3,7
- 3,8
- (Notice no "4" in the list, I just added other "pairs" for show that 1 and 3 are the lowest.  If 4 is in the list like 4,0 or 4,null, I can make that work too.)

I'm using SQL Server 2012.  Thanks!

Comment: So a duplicate group has the same _number_ of values as well as them being the same values?

Comment: I can see from your first example that you want to identify groups 1&2 and 3&5 as having duplicates, but I cannot see any duplicates in your second example.

Comment: I didn't included the extra data, the EXTRA values would be: {6,1},{6,2},{6,3},{7,1},{7,2},{7,4},{8,1},{8,2},{8,4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--This code produced the results I was looking for in the original post.  

WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    column1,
    COUNT(*) c
  FROM #tbl
  GROUP BY column1
),
tt AS(
SELECT
  t1.column1 as 'winner',
  t2.column1 as 'loser'
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON (
  t1.c = t2.c AND
  t1.column1 < t2.column1
)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT column2 FROM #tbl WHERE column1 = t1.column1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT column2 FROM #tbl WHERE column1 = t2.column1
)
)
SELECT fullList.winner, fullList.loser
FROM
(  SELECT winner FROM tt tt1
   EXCEPT
   SELECT loser FROM tt tt2
) winnerList
JOIN tt fullList on winnerList.winner = fullList.winner
ORDER BY fullList.winner, fullList.loser
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    column1,
    COUNT(*) c
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY column1
)
SELECT
  t1.column1,
  t2.column1
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON (
  t1.c = t2.c AND
  t2.column1 > t1.column1
)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT column2 FROM MyTable WHERE column1 = t1.column1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT column2 FROM MyTable WHERE column1 = t2.column1
)
```

Comment: This works perfect on the initial data set provided, but on an expanded data set it doesn't work right. (I added more values in my comment in that OP.)  Thanks for you help, I'll keep working with this code.

Comment: Note: this code lists all of the pairs when a lower ID is present.  For example if 1,2,6 and 9 are all of the same sets it would return:{1,2},{1,6},{1,9},{2,6},{2,9},{6,9}, where I just want the first 3 values returned.

Comment: I tweaked the code in this answer to make it correct (you deserve the credit), but it has to be peer reviewed first for others to see it.  As soon as that is done, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'd use a second query to denormalize the output.  This query is already O(N^3 log^2 N)

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1,column2 from my_table
group by column1,column2
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

will give you list of duplicate records.

Comment: Thanks, but my example above has 0 "duplicate records" and this would return 0 results.  I have a sequence of values in column 2 that I am trying to find duplicates of.

Comment: How many distinct value in your column2? If not so many i may come up with some hard code.